# Laravel 5 Redirect doesn't work from AJAX GET url

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a date picker and I put a jquery listener to it on change:

```
$('#viewmonth').datepicker({language: 'ja', autoclose: true,  minViewMode: 'months', format: $('#month_format').text(),})
.change(function() {
    let date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    date = date.getFullYear() + '-' + month;

    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type:'GET',
        url:'/head/sale/h_2_501/changeMonth',
        data: {'viewmonth': date}
    });
});
```

When the date is changed, it redirects to changeMonth function:

```
public function changeMonth() {
    $viewmonth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Request::input('viewmonth')));
    $viewmonth = mb_convert_kana($viewmonth, 'a');

    error_log($viewmonth);

    $filter = $this->pageInfo['filter'];

    $filter['viewmonth'] = $viewmonth;

    $this->updateFilterData($filter);

    return redirect()->route('head.sale.h_2_501');
}
```

Inside this function, I am changing the date of the query I use to display some data. The problem is after redirecting to the index route inside changeMonth, the results display doesn't change but the query changed. How do I also update the data displayed?

Comment: You're calling `changeMonth()` via AJAX so the response will be returned to your `$.ajax()` caller (via the `success` callback or `done` method). You don't appear to be attempting to handle the response at all

Answer (score 1):

First remove `return redirect()->route('head.sale.h_2_501');` from `changeMonth()` function.

Then add it to the AJAX success call.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    type:'GET',
    url:'/head/sale/h_2_501/changeMonth',
    data: {'viewmonth': date},
    success: function (response) {

        // this is the redirect after your changeMonth() function succeed.
        window.location = '{{ route('head.sale.h_2_501') }}'
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't call the route() correctly here, I'm getting a different route

Comment: This is the url it redirects to after calling that: http://127.0.0.1:8000/head/sale/%7B%7Broute('head.sale.h_2_501')%7D%7D

Comment: isn't this a `.blade.php` file? If it's not, you can't use `{{ }}` these. then you have to use the exact url, example `window.location = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/head/sale/whatever_your_other_parts'`.